# Question on intersecting lines.

Tags: geometry

AB and CD are two straight lines meeting at O and XY is another straight line. Show that in general two points can be found in XY which are equidistant from AB and CD. Also When is there only one such points?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Where are the points in the plane equidistant from lines $AB$ and $CD$?

Answer (score 2):

The points in the plane which are equidistant to $AB$ and $CD$ are the points on the angle bisector of $\angle AOC,\angle DOB$ and the angle bisector of $\angle COB,\angle DOA$ (blue lines in the figure).

[image]

Because the line $XY$ generally intersects both angle bisectors, then it passes through two points equidistant to $AB$ and $CD$.

The line $XY$ passes through only one such point if and only if it is parallel to, but does not coincide with, one of the angle bisectors, or it passes through O without coinciding with either angle bisector.

Added note: the line $XY$ passes through *infinitely many* such points if and only if it coincides with one of the angle bisectors.

Comment: [Enforcement of quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|128.8139).  Please focus on helping askers improve their questions, prior to answering very low quality questions.  Thanks!